# How to type selected elements of an array in double quotes

Tags: arrays, perl

Here, I'm trying to print the 2nd, 3rd and 4th elements of an array in double quotes and I've only been able to do it in single quotes.

```
my @fruits = ("apples", "oranges", "guavas", "passionfruits", "grapes");
my $a = 1;
while ($a<4){
    print " '$fruits[$a]' \n";
    $a += 1;
}
```

But I can't do this in single quotes. When I change the single quotes to double quotes and vice versa, it prints `"$fruits[$a]"\n` three times instead.
And when I change all quotes to double quotes, it gives an error which I understand why.
   Please I really need help here.

And if I could get a way to print all three elements in double quotes without having to use a loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use `"` in a string delimited by `"`, escape it.

```
"foo: \"$bar\"\n"
```

You could also switch the delimiter (keeping in mind that `"..."` is short for `qq"..."`).

```
qq{foo: "$bar"\n}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Always use

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   ```

   even in the shortest Perl scripts.

   In case of typos in the code, Perl will usually issue errors if you include them. Without, Perl will happily do weird, wrong and pointless things silently.

---

2. Your example will not print the entire array. Instead you will get:

   ```
    'oranges' 
    'guavas' 
    'passionfruits'
   ```

   The first index of an array is `0` and therefore `'apples'` is skipped because `$a` is initialized with `1`. The loop is also exited due to reaching the value `4` before printing out `'grapes'`.

   In order to print the entire array you would do:

   - if you need to use the index value `$i` somewhere:

     ```
     for my $i (0 .. $#fruits) {
         print " $i: '$fruits[$i]' \n";
     }
     ```

     (`$#fruits` is the last index if `@fruits`, equal to the the size of the array minus 1. Since this array has 5 items, the index values range from 0 to 4)
   - otherwise:

     ```
     foreach my $current_fruit (@fruits) {
         print " '$current_fruit' \n";
     }
     ```

     where `$current_fruit` is set to each item in the array `@fruits` in its turn.

---

3. Quotes in Perl function as operators, and depending on which ones you use, they may or may not do various things with the included string.

   - In your examples, the double quotes will do interpolation on the string, substituting the value of `$fruits[$a]` and replacing the escape sequence `\n`. Therefore:

     ```
     print " '$fruits[$a]' \n";
     ```

     (for `$a == 1`) becomes:

     ```
      'oranges'
     ```
   - Single quotes, in contrast, will *not* do interpolation.

     Only single quotes themselves (and backslashes preceding single quotes) need to be escaped with a backslash. (Other backslashes can optionally be escaped.) All other character sequences will appear as they are, so the argument to `print` in:

     ```
     print ' "$fruits[$a]" \n';
     ```

     is considered entirely a literal string and thus

     ```
      "$fruits[$a]" \n "$fruits[$a]" \n "$fruits[$a]" \n
     ```

     is printed out.

   ---

   To get the desired output, there are multiple ways to go about it:

   1. The simplest way - but not easiest to read for complex strings - is to use double quotes and escape the included quotes:

      ```
      print " \"$fruits[$a]\" \n";
      ```
   2. You can use an generic notation for `"..."`, which is `qq{...}` where `{}` are either a pair of braces (any of `()`, `[]`, `{}` or `<>`) or the same other non-whitespace, non-word character, e.g.:

      ```
      print qq{ "$fruits[$a]" \n};
      ```

      or

      ```
      print qq! "$fruits[$a]" \n!;
      ```
   3. You can concatenate the string out of parts that you quote separately:

      ```
      print ' "' . $fruits[$a] . '"' . " \n";
      ```

   Which is easiest to read in code will depend on the complexity of the string and the variables contained: For really long strings with complex dereferences, indeces and hash keys you might want to use option 3, whereas for short ones 2 would be the best.

   My entire edited code:

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my @fruits = ("apples", "oranges", "guavas", "passionfruits", "grapes");

   for my $i (0 .. $#fruits) {
       print " $i: \"$fruits[$i]\" \n";
       print qq< $i: "$fruits[$i]" \n>;
       print ' ' . $i . ': "' . $fruits[$i] . '"' . " \n";
   }

   foreach my $current_fruit (@fruits) {
       print " \"$current_fruit\" \n";
       print qq¤ "$current_fruit" \n¤;
       print ' "' . $current_fruit . '"' . " \n";
   }
   ```

   ---

   You can learn more about the different quotes in Perl from the perldoc (or man on UNIX-like systems) page `perlop` and its [section titled "Quote and Quote-like Operators"](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

Comment: Re "*Your example will not print the entire array.*", Nor did they want to